# how can i sort file elements in python?

Tags: python

I have to sort some elements in a text file that contains the names with the schedules of some teachers. Searching on google, I found this program:

```
def sorting(filename):
  infile = open(filename)
  words = []
  for line in infile:
    temp = line.split()
    for i in temp:
      words.append(i)
  infile.close()
  words.sort()
  outfile = open("result.txt", "w")
  for i in words:
    outfile.writelines(i)
    outfile.writelines(" ")
  outfile.close()
sorting("file.txt")
```

The code works, but it sorts the elements of the file on a single line, while I want it to be written as in the file, but in alphabetical and numerical orders. To unterstand it, let's say I have this file:

```
c
a
b
```

What I want is to sort it like this:

```
a
b
c
```

but it sorts it like this:

```
a b c
```

I use python 3.10. Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def sorting(filename):
  infile = open(filename)
  words = []
  for line in infile:
    temp = line.split()
    for i in temp:
      words.append(i)
  infile.close()
  words.sort()
  outfile = open("result.txt", "w")
  for i in words:
    outfile.writelines(i)
    outfile.writelines("\n") # edited Instead of ' ' write '\n'
  outfile.close()
sorting("test.txt")
```